# remove whitespace from bash variable

Tags: bash

Assuming a variable contains spaces, newlines, and tabs followed by some text, why does this:

```
${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}  # strip var of everything 
                                # but whitespace
                                # then remove what's left 
                                # (i.e. the whitespace) from var
```

remove the white space and leave the text, but this:

```
${var##[:space:]*}  # strip all whitespace from var
```

does not?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If I set `var="  This is a test  "`, both your suggestions do not work;
just the leading stuff is removed.
Why not use the replace functionality that removes all occurrences of whitespace and not just the first:

```
 ${var//[[:space:]]}
```

Answer (score 4):

[:space:] is a character class. It's only valid if it is nested inside another set of [ ].

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know that character classes required nested brackets.

Comment: @MCS - This is documented in regex(7) ("man 7 regex" to read it). Most modern regex implementations include support for the POSIX named character classes, so you can read about them in perl's perlre man page, for example, as well.

Answer (score 1):

flolo's answer is documented in the "Parameter Substitution" section of the bash man page. Another source of documentation is the [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) section of the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). The ABS guide includes basic documentation with excellent example code.

Answer (score 0):

What about $(echo $var)

```
> a="   123 456  " ; a2="$(echo $a)" ; echo "a=\"${a}\" a2=\"${a2}\""
a="   123 456  " a2="123 456"
```