# sed: unterminated s command from bash script

Tags: bash, sed

This exact code was working in another script. I copied the function over and now it keeps
giving the unterminated 's' command error.

```
sed "
        s@<%BRANCH-NAME%>@${_loc_name}@g
        s@<%BRANCH-ADDR%>@${_loc_strt}@g
        s@<%BRANCH-CTY%>@${_loc_city}@g
        s@<%CUST-NAME%>@${_pat_name}@g
        s@<%CUST-ADDR%>@${_pat_addr}@
        s@<%CUST-CTY%>@${_pat_city}@
        s@<%BARCODE%>@${_barcode}@g
        s@<%DATE%>@${_date}@
        s@<%TITLE%>@${_title}@
        s@<%AUTHOR%>@${_auth}@
        s@<%PRICE%>@${_price}@" "$_template"
```

In response to requests for possible values:

These are huge files and this function is in a for loop. I use it to format forms for mailing. More info here: [BASH: importing data from flat file into template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764521/bash-importing-data-from-flat-file-into-template)

So this function worked for certain directories but I've hit a snag with this recent one.

I grepped for slash characters on the advice of kev below ...none found except '/'. Possibly
'silent' newlines.

```
find ./ -name "mail.TMP" -type f -exec grep -E '\n' {} \;
```

possible values would be things like:

```
${pat_name}
```

Hermann Hesse c/o His Mother

```
${loc_name}
```

Pandora SR home c/o Harmony City Hall

So ...maybe it's a quoting issue?

Comment: Do any of your `${_loc_name}`, `${_loc_strt}`, etc. variables contain an `@` character?

Comment: Can you please paste your complete error?

Comment: Is this a `sed` script or are you using it inside regular `bash` script? If it is a `sed` script then you don't need `sed` and the `quotes`. If it is inside regular script then you need to add option `-e`.

Comment: @JaypalSingh: No, you don't need `-e`; `sed s/this/that/` is equivalent to `sed -e s/this/that/`.  (The `-e` option is probably necessary in some ambiguous cases, but this isn't one of them.)  And the question title says it's a bash script.

Comment: @KeithThompson You're right!! Sorry about that. Then as you stated in the comments earlier, it could be that variable has `@` which is throwing it off.

Comment: I'm changing command characters around and still getting these errors.

Comment: How would you quote this? Is there a better way with strings with spaces?

Comment: Show us the values of `${_loc_name}` et al.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ _loc_name=$'xxx\nyyy'
$ echo '<%BRANCH-NAME%>' | sed "s@<%BRANCH-NAME%>@${_loc_name}@g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unterminated `s' command
```

Does any `$var` contain `newline`? Please `echo` them all to check.

```
$ echo "$_loc_name"
xxx
yyy
```

Comment: I believe that's the issue ...though it's actually a name field eg.,. These are massive files --- is there a way to

Comment: As I was saying --- is there a way to quote around this?

Comment: I see two articles that talk about stripping white space from a variable (which may help you): [article 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable) and [article 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324167/remove-whitespace-from-bash-variable). Are these replacement variables read in from some file? If so, article 1 might be what you want.

Comment: @JonahBishop - Dude, I think you're right about white space. I'm using the IFS to push this through a for loop -- specifically mentioned in the article you mention. Wil;l lokk at this more closely tomorrow. Thanks!